# jsTree child node does not get selected after OPEN_ALL

Tags: jstree

I successfully opened a jsTree node branch with below line of code.

```
$('#jsTree').jstree("open_all", currentNode);
```

After this line, I need to select currentNode's first child. For that, I wrote below line of code.

```
currentNode = currentNode.children("ul").children("li:first");
```

But, it's not working!

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the new current node: `$('#jsTree').jstree("select_node", currentNode);`.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code will **ONLY** open the child nodes of the specified node (i.e. currentNode)

```
$('#jsTree').jstree("open_all", currentNode);
```

The next statement that you are using is **ONLY** updating the reference of currentNode from parent node to the first child node.

```
currentNode = currentNode.children("ul").children("li:first");
```

This statement has nothing to do with the selection of the node. To select the first child node you have to call the select method explicitly

```
$('#jsTree').jstree("select_node", currentNode);
```

**Note:** Depending on your data-source, you many not be able to get the reference of first child using the above code. In my test case, having JSON data-source, the reference was available through

```
currentNode = currentNode.children("ul").children("li")[0];
```

or

```
currentNode = currentNode.children("ul").children("li:first")[0];
```